# Important window drivers regarding audio are missing and Audio not working

Tags: proxy, streaming, nvidia, clock, trusted

I did something crazy. While installing or removing some junk (softwares) from my pc and then suddenly i noticed that red cross sign appeared on my volume icon and no sound was there. when i checked the device manager following drivers had a small yellow triangular mark beneath them and audio was not working.

1,  Microsoft Streaming Clock Proxy,

2,  Microsoft Streaming Quality Manager Proxy,

3,  Microsoft Streaming Service Proxy,

4,  Microsoft Streaming Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter,

5,  Microsoft Streaming Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter, (no that's not a misprint, That one was listed twice)

6,  Microsoft Trusted Audio Drivers.

7,  NVIDIA High Definition Audio.

8,  Realtek High Definition Audio.

I am using windows 10 and my hardware is Dell optiplex 7010, Corei7 3.3Ghz, 8gb Ram, 500 gb Hard drive , 2gb Nvidia Geforce 210 Graphics card.

Thank you ever so much for sharing any knowledge you have about this to fix my pretty dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**, I Am using Sony Vaio SVS1512DCXB, Windows 10 Home

**I had the same problem**

*Device SW{97ebaacc-95bd-11d0-a3ea-00a0c9223196}{53172480-4791-11D0-A5D6-28DB04C10000} had a problem starting.
Driver Name: ksfilter.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Service: **MSPCLOCK**
Lower Filters: 
Upper Filters: 
Problem: 0x27
Problem Status: 0xC0000034*

*Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service HdAudAddService for Device Instance ID HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2806&SUBSYS_104D6500&REV_1000\4&ED7485A&0&0301 with the following status: 0.*

**Try this**

Update all drivers

and

In the command line, as administrator, run the command: 
**c:\>sc config MSPCLOCK start= demand**

and

Remove all traces of antivirus, such as kaspersky, using kavremvr.exe from https://media.kaspersky.com/utilities/ConsumerUtilities/kavremvr.exe